# How to make custom control with ListBox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

[image]

I want to make horizontal ListBox with customized item template, so I make a basic template of it.

However, I couldn't find an example of binding 'things' to that WPF XAML, especially with ListBox filled with customized items.

I simply want to dynamically add/remove items in the ListBox with Image, Label, ComboBox with previously filled with number 1 to 10.

the ADD/REMOVE button will be placed outside WPF control, it means that the buttons will be on the Main Window Form.

Also, there are TextBox and picture selector in the Main Window Form so that I can change the text and image.

Below is code behind XAML :

```
Public Class listSequence

Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    listbox.Items.Add("hi")
    listbox.Items.Add("there")

End Sub
End Class
```

Below is XAML :

```
<ListBox Name="listbox" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Padding="10" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Aqua" CornerRadius="0" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image />
                    <Label Content="{Binding}" />   
                    <TextBlock Text="hi" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cboRepeat" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="RepeatCounter" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say we have a basic class named `Item`:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged 
    public string ImagePath { get; set; } // properly on these properties
}
```

And a collection of these in a view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Now to display these items in the UI, we use a `ListBox` and set the `ItemsSource` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
</ListBox>
```

When it comes to defining the `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, you need to understand that this `DataTemplate` will be applied to each item and that *it has access to all of the properties defined in the `Item` class*:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Therefore, you can access the properties in the collection class as shown above. You can find out the full story by looking at the [`ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.